# How to check in JNI if java class exists?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

If im using this:

```
if(!env->FindClass("com/test/app")){
    Log("Not found");
    return 0;
}
```

I got error: no such class

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html), `FindClass` can result in a variety of (Java) exceptions being thrown.

It is an error to make any further JNI calls with a pending Java exception. So you need to, at a minimum, clear the exception using `env->ExceptionClear()`.